# Не работает commands discord py

Tags: python, discord.py

Я правда не понимаю в чем прикол. Задумал делать большого бота, так сказать один большой проект и меня уже второй час трясет, что я не могу найти ошибку в такой маленькой части кода. Да ее тут и нет. Я вообще не понимаю что происходит и что уже делать. Помогите пожалуйста понять, почему этот малюююсенький код не работает.

```
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='+')



@bot.command()
async def test(ctx, arg):
    await ctx.send(arg)


bot.run('token')
```

Comment: простите, а что вы ждете от этого кода?..

Comment: Что конкретно не работает?

Comment: Этот код взят с документации discord py. Если я пишу +test hello, то он пишет в этот канал hello
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html

Comment: Какую выдает ошибку? Я у себя запустил и всё работает

Comment: Он не выдает ошибку. Он просто не выполняет это действие

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте, работает ли этот бот в личных сообщениях. Уверен, что там он ответит.
Если так и есть, то добавьте после импорта вот эти строчки:

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
```

Затем зайдите на discord.com/developers и выберите Вашего бота. Затем зайдите в раздел Bot и поставьте галочку на "MESSAGE CONTENT INTENT
Required for your bot to receive message content in most messages"

Теперь бот будет работать везде.

Comment: Cпасибо большое, заработал

Comment: Всегда рад помочь!